# SQLServerのデッドロックグラフの読み方

Tags: sql-server

JavaEEで開発したアプリケーションで、デッドロックが大量に発生しました。
SQLServerのsystem_healthを見てみると、あるテーブルXに対するDELETEのトランザクション同士によるデッドロックです。

system_healthからこの画像が見れるのですが、これの読み取り方を教えてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

黒塗りで消してある部分は
Object name：「テーブルX」
Index name：「テーブルXのインデックスY」
です。
「キーロック」の枠が２つありますが、どちらも同じ内容でした。

### 以下の解釈は正しいですか？

#### 1. 獲得済みロックとロック要求の解釈

- プロセスID367 が、ロック対象Bの更新ロックを獲得済み(Owner Mode: U)
- プロセスID391 が、ロック対象Aの排他ロックを獲得済み(Owner Mode: X)

という状況において、
お互いに逆のロック対象に対する更新ロックを要求(Request Mode: U)して、デッドロックを引き起こしている。

#### 2. ロック対象の解釈

ロック対象A、Bはともに、インデックスY全体に対するロックである。
つまり、AとBは同じものであり、同一の対象でデッドロックが発生している。

### 正しいとした場合の疑問

#### 同一対象への更新ロックは競合するのでは？

[この解説](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/2014-toc/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2014#lock-compatibility)によると、更新ロックは共有ロックとしか互換性がなく、同一対象に2つの更新ロックは持てないはずです。
従って、私の解釈の2と矛盾します。

恐らく解釈が間違っていると思うのですが・・・
どなたか、正しい解釈を教えていただけないでしょうか。
※最終的には原因究明と回避策を検討しますが、まずはこのsystem_healthの情報を正しく解釈したいという主旨の質問です。

### 環境の情報

- SQLServerのバージョンは2017
- トランザクション分離レベルは READ COMMITTED

  - Is Read Committed Snapshot On = False
  - スナップショット分離を許可 = False

### 追加情報

- テーブルXにトリガーはありません
- [Understanding the graphical representation of the SQL Server Deadlock Graph](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-graphical-representation-sql-server-deadlock-graph/)
  グラフの読み方はこれを見て理解したつもりです。英語が苦手なので解釈に自信が無いのですが・・・

  > Owner edge
  >
  > Occurs when resources are waiting on processes. In this case the Person.person table is waiting on process 62 to release it.

  テーブル「Person.person」はプロセス62がロックを解放するのを待っている＝プロセス62がテーブル「Person.person」のロックを持っている、ですよね？
- SQL発行時にヒントは含めていません。

  - ロック対象を指定していないです。

Comment: トランザクション分離レベルは SERIALIZABLE でしょうか？SQLServerのバージョンもお書きください。2012以降とは分かりますが。

Comment: ありがとうございます、追記しました

Comment: 当該テーブルにトリガーなどが設定されていたりしますでしょうか？

Comment: 同じようなグラフを発見しました。 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saponsqlserver/2013/01/31/deadlock-analysis-basic/
 私はまだ理解できていませんが、参考になりますでしょうか。

Comment: SNAPSHOT分離レベルとは別にREAD_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOTがありますが、どちらも使用されていないということでしょうか？

Comment: SNAPSHOTの件、2つ設定があったのですね。どちらも使用していません。設定項目を確認したので、その項目名で追記しました

Comment: 先ほどの記事の次の投稿にまさに答えと思われる例と説明がありました。 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saponsqlserver/2015/01/18/deadlock-analysis-examples/

Comment: ありがとうございます。その記事の１つ目のケースでしょうか。実際にはインデックスがきちんと揃っていて、Index ScanではなくIndex Seekであることを確認しているので、その記事にある解決方法（to create an fitting index for the WHERE clause to get the two thread to seek instead to scan the index）は使えません。デッドロック発生時間帯に、当該処理への大量のリクエストがありましたので、恐らく、大量ロックからのロックエスカレーションのせいで、その記事のIndex Scanでのロックと同じ状況になっているのかなと推測してはいますが、その辺りの原因と解決方法については別の質問をあげようと思っています。

Comment: ロックの表示がキーロックなので、キー範囲ロックだと思われますが、該当テーブルのロックは行ロック指定ですか？SQLでロックヒント等は指定していませんか？

Comment: 追記しました。ロック対象は指定していません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ちょっと試してみた範囲では、Request Mode: Xでデッドロックしましたが、ほぼ同じ現象を出せました

解釈の間違ってる点ですが

> ロック対象A、Bはともに、インデックスY全体に対するロックである。

インデックス全体に対するロックではなく、インデックスのキー範囲に対するロックです
なので対象インデックスが同じでも、違うキーに対するロックは複数が同時に存在しえます

対策案は、
同一キーに対する削除があるなら、nowait指定で削除でのロック待ちをなくすぐらいですかね
こちらはデッドロックではなくロックタイムアウトでエラーはでるので適切なハンドリングが必要ですが